# Which clause a preposition belong to matters to determine whether who or whom is used?

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, who-whom

In general, both *who* and *whom* can be used in the following sentence, although *whom* may be preferred in strict grammar:

> I knew who/whom he was talking with.

I think in the following sentence, *whom* should always be used because *whom* is preceded by a preposition:

> I knew with whom he was talking.

#### Question:

Does *whom* should always be used, even if the preposition is from the main clause?
E.g.:

> I was talking with who(m) he knew.

Comment: Yes, but your last two examples are unnatural.

Comment: FYI, "I was talking with who/whom he knew" is not a grammatically correct sentence.  "I was talking to someone he knew." "Who/whom" is not used this way.

Comment: By far the easiest way to deal with this is ***always*** use ***who***. If you want to be slightly "adventurous", you might consider using ***whom*** if and only if it's preceded by the preposition ***to***, but it's really not worth digging any deeper than that today. The vast majority of younger native speakers have already abandoned ***whom*** anyway, so you'll be in good company just copying them.